# Is precession a property of asymetric objects only? How to explain Larmor precession?

Tags: symmetry, precession

Is precession a property  of asymmetric objects only? How to explain Larmor precession? A proton could be asymmetric due to its compositeness but what about electrons?

Comment: Symmetric tops can precess. Larmor precession does not rely on gravity (or the mass distribution of an object). Rather, Larmor precession relates to how a magnetic moment rotates around a magnetic field. The underlying physics is similar but Larmor precession has nothing to do with (a)symmetry of the mass distribution of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between torque-free and torque-induced precession. This is because in the Newtonian equation for the angular velocity of a rotating rigid-body, there are terms that seperately involve the "external" and "internal". Asymmetry in the mass distribution gives rise to the "internal" contribution, where as phenomena like Larmor precession involve external torques (magnetic field interacting with magnetic moment).

The Newtonian equation of motion for the angular velocity of a rigid-body (i.e. a fixed, solid object), with respect to an inertial reference-frame with the object at rest, is the following

$$\frac{d}{dt}\vec\omega = \mathbf{I}^{-1}\left[\underset{\textrm{"external"}}{\underbrace{\vec\tau_{\textrm{ext}}}}-\underset{\textrm{"internal"}}{\underbrace{\frac{d\mathbf I}{dt}\vec\omega}}\right]$$

For a body with asymmetric mass distribution, the "internal" term will indeed change as the body rotates - the inertia tensor depends on the body's orientation with respect to the inertial axes.

In the case of Larmor precession, a magnetic field couples to the object's magnetic moment: $\vec\tau_{\textrm{ext}} = \vec\mu\times \vec B=\gamma \vec L \times \vec B$ where $\vec \mu=\gamma \vec L$ is the magnetic moment, and $\vec L$ is the (total) angular momentum.